# 404 Error when clicking Add Reviews in Admin Panel

Tags: admin, ce-1.9.0.1, review, 404-page

I'm having problems with adding Reviews in the backend.
The review system works, because they can be added in the front end by guests and users.
Here's the list of reviews:

[image: Review List]

I can edit these reviews as normal.

[image: Edit Review]

But when I try to create a new review in the back end, I get the following 404:

[image: Add Review - 404 Error]

What can I do?

regards
Phil

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846783/magento-admin-screens-add-new-review-button-not-working-and-generates-a-404-erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Rating/Detailed.php

and find function getRating()

in this function isset "->setStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId())"

where Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId() return empty.

Rewrite this block and put Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()